# Javascript regex parsing smilies and ignoring urls

Tags: javascript, regex, parsing

I want to parse input from user and replace all smiley "codes" with the image of the smiley. I've come across a issue when a user writes an url then the :/ of http:// and https:// gets replaced. The current regex I use for the :/ replace is "/://g" and I need help changing this so it does not replace the :/ if it's in a http:// or https://

Example of input

> Please have a look at this link http://stackoverflow.com that could help you :). If it does not help :/ then please use https://www.google.com

Should parse to output

```
Please have a look at this link http://stackoverflow.com that could help you <img src="/smile.png"/>. If it does not help <img src="/sidesmile.png"/> then please use https://www.google.com
```

Here's a regex101.com example: https://regex101.com/r/bB6vK2/1 (As you can see the http:// and https:// is also selected and replaced here)

Answer (score 1):

You can match and capture the `:/` that you want to keep and just match the `:/` that will be replaced.

```
/((?:https?|ftps?):\/)|:\//ig
```

See, `((?:https?|ftps?):\/)` is the `:/` that is preceded with `http` or `ftp`, and they can be restored in an anonymous function inside `replace`.

Here is a snippet:

```js
var str = 'Please have a look at this link http://stackoverflow.com that could help you :). If it does not help :/ then please use https://www.google.com. Now, a difficult one:/';
var result = str.replace(/((?:https?|ftps?):\/)|:\//ig, function (m, grp1) {
   return grp1 ? grp1 : '<img src="/sidesmile.png"/>';
  });
alert(result);
```

Comment: I like this regex in its simplicity, however it requires that there's a space between the smiley "code" and the word. i.e. if user write ".. does not help:/" it will not be parsed. If only we didn't have to make this for users :)

Comment: I have replaced the code with a more flexible solution. Feel free to add more exclusions to the first capturing group `((?:https?|ftps?):\/)`. E.g. to exclude `gopher:` use `((?:https?|ftps?|gother):\/)`. Probably `(\b(?:https?|ftps?):\/)` is even safer (as `http` and `ftp` must be whole words then due to `\b`).

Answer (score 1):

Updated regex for `:/`:

```
:\/([^\/]|$)
```

Replace to:

```
<img ... >$1
```

Explanation - this has two variants in it:

1. `:\/[^\/]` - `:\` with next char not being `\` but this will omit smiles at end of text (no char after smiley).
2. `:\/$` - smiley at end of text.

As whole regex matches smiley with char after it (e.g. space) so we have to put that mached char (or nothing if it is end of text) to replace string.

Comment: Looks good, the only issue I can see is that it matches the next character after smiley code. If users writes for example ":/:/:/:/" without spaces after each other: https://regex101.com/r/jO7cW7/1 . It also matches a white space after so in the replace I have to add a space at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's not strict regex answer, but you may concider replacing `http://` with some temporary constant, do the smiles replace and rollback constant into `http://`:

```
input
  .replace(/http(s?):\/\//g, '__http$1__') // escape http:// keyword
  .replace(/:\//g, 'SMILE') // do the smiles replacement
  .replace(/__http(s?)__/g, 'http$1://') // rollback constant
;
```

Comment: a URL can have protocols other than http or https